# Повторный запуск программы С++

Tags: c++

У нас есть главное окно программы (см. 1 изобр.). Если в поле «Ввод:» ввести любой ответ, с которым программа не знакома (то есть, сработает `else`), то мы получаем бесконечный цикл повторного открытия главного окна (см. 2 изобр.). Из-за чего это происходит?

Если я не прав насчёт такой реализации «повторного» запуска программы, то почему же так нельзя сделать?

[image: описание1][image: описание2]

```
int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int setting;
    std::cout << "Укажите тип ввода данных:\n1 — С клавиатуры\n2 — Из файла\nВвод: ";
    std::cin >> setting;
    if (setting == 2){
        open_and_read();
    }
    else if (setting == 1) {
        per_enter();
        int setting;
        std::cout << "Хотите повторить ввод исходных данныех?\n1 — Да\n2 — Нет\nВвод: ";
        std::cin >> setting;
        if (setting == 1 || "Да") {
            main();
        }
        else if (setting == 2 || "Нет") {
            std::cout << "Работа программы заврешена." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Ответ не соответствует ни одному из доступных вариантов ввода." << std::endl;
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Поддержу Harry - рекурсивный вызов `main()` - это не хорошо. А главное - абсолютно не нужно. Поместите ваши `if` в цикл, и выходите из него по нужному условию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с мелочи — вызывать `main()` рекурсивно — очень плохая практика.

А теперь к сути.

```
int setting;
std::cin >> setting;
```

Допустим, вы вводите не число. Что получается? `cin` переходит в состояние fail, все дальнейшие операции с ним игнорируются, т.е. не происходит никакого чтения к консоли, выполнение переходит к следующей строке.

После ввода лучше всегда проверять состояние потока, и если с ним беда — очистить его (`cin.clear()`) и сбросить буфер ввода...